# Difference between :host::ng-deep .class and .class :host::ng-deep?

Tags: angular, sass

What is the difference between the below two in scss,
Give some examples in snippet.

```
:host::ng-deep .content-body {
...
}
```

and

```
.content-body :host::ng-deep {
...
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all, `:host` and `::ng-deep` are Angular constructs, nothing to do with SASS

Now, let's say you have a component named "blog" defined in Angular and blog.component.scss is where you define the SASS for it. Then,

**CASE 1 :**

```
:host::ng-deep .content-body {
...
}
```

will apply style defined to any element with the class `.content-body` inside the component scope. Eg:

```
<div>
  <blog>
    <div class="content-body"></div>
    <div class="some-extra-content">
      <div class="content-body"></div>
    </div>
  </blog>
</div>
```

In the above case, both the `class="content-body"` `div`s will have the style applied.

**CASE 2 :**

```
.content-body :host::ng-deep {
...
}
```

will apply style defined to only the component instances which are defined inside an element which has `class="content-body"`
Eg:

```
<blog></blog> <!-- Style won't be applied here -->
<div class="content-body">
  <blog></blog> <!-- Style will be applied here -->
</div>
```

You can [check a StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muojc5). In the StackBlitz example, `color:red` is applied because of **CASE 1** inside `app.component.css` and `color:yellow` is applied to only one of the `hello` components because of **CASE 2**.
Feel free to fork the Stackblitz and play around.

**NOTE :** If you don't know already, the shadow piercing combinator `::ng-deep` [is being deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)