How to apply z-index on PrimeNG dropdown
I'm using Angular 18 and PrimeNG.  I have a PrimeNG dropdown that is visually being clipped by a PrimeNG table footer.  I've tried to apply a higher z-index on a variety of p-dropdown css classes, but with no success.  Has anybody had any success showing all of a dropdown?
The following is an example:
StackBlitz Dropdown-Demo

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

One way you can target your element with :host::ng-deep.
You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566274/difference-between-hostng-deep-class-and-class-hostng-deep.  Hopefully, you can achieve what you're trying to.

@DarkBee, your right.  I tried it in StackBlitz and had no CSS problem.  I'm working on identifying what is limiting the dropdown in my component.

@naeem: (deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep per angular.io

Add additional parameter appendTo="body" to your dropdown component.
<p-dropdown
          id="ExpenseTypeId"
          name="ExpenseTypeId"
          [options]="expenseTypes"
          [style]="{'width':'145px'}"
          #ExpenseTypeId="ngModel"
          appendTo="body"
          [(ngModel)]="addExpenseMiscGrid.ExpenseTypeId"
          placeholder="Select an expense"
        ></p-dropdown>

Here is an example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bhiqq6-a2kjxv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-editable-demo.html
Some additional resource to read about it:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-primeng-dialog-overlays-inside/
